# Unsupported operating system with Docker on windows 10 with wsl2

Tags: docker, laravel-sail

I installed docker and downloaded an ubuntu distro to run with laravel sail,planing to use swoole php,and made it default,also made wsl version to 2
[image]

with docker-compose.yml ready from laravel sail docker-compose.yml:
[image]

but every time I try to run the sail up cmd,it gives me this error " Unsupported operating system [MINGW64_NT-10.0]. Laravel Sail supports macOS, Linux, and Windows (WSL2)."

[image]

any ideas how to fix this ?

Comment: Tried using cmd.exe?

Comment: i did,but it do no work,i saw some ppl say i have to use bash not cmd,because bash is interpreted

Comment: cmd : " ./vendor/bin/sail up "
response : " '.' is not recognized as an internal or external command,
operable program or batch file. "

cmd : " /vendor/bin/sail up "
response : " 'vendor' is not recognized as an internal or external command,
operable program or batch file. "

cmd : " vendor/bin/sail up "
response : " 'vendor' is not recognized as an internal or external command,
operable program or batch file. "

even though i did php artisan sail:install

Comment: cmd is interpreted too... -- you have to do `vendor\bin\sail up` in cmd, no `./` or `/` sep

Comment: C:\wamp64\www\mtqdma\l_8\mzaedh>vendor\bin\sail up
|
/bin/bash: C:\wamp64\www\mtqdma\l_8\mzaedh\vendor\bin\/../laravel/sail/bin/sail: No such file or directory

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You need to run the sail up command from inside your WSL2 Ubuntu Image not directly from your terminal. Once you do that it should work ok

Comment: do i have to cd to the laravel project or just anywhere ?
also i saw some ppl say that i have to move my project to the image,to directory same as this as example

Comment: \\wsl$\Ubuntu-20.04\home\wagih\mzaedh

Comment: You have to `cd /mnt/c/path/to/laravel` @AhmedWagihRefaey

Comment: thanks, it worked, no one mentioned it at the tutorials, although it needed some permissions to run the command

but right now after the container downloaded and stuff,i cant run the project

Comment: [Mon Mar  1 02:25:38 2021] PHP 8.0.2 Development Server (http://0.0.0.0:80) started

this is at the ubuntu image terminal

but once i run that at the browser it gives nothing

Comment: let me serve some more tutorial, it seems i'm missing lots of untold things

Comment: the problem now is that the container is running i docker,and once i type localhost in my browse,it opens the wamp homepage,although wamp is not running, any ideas ?

Comment: Thank you all,it worked, i had to change wamp port to 8090 instead of 8080 to solve the confilect

Comment: Check out my comprehensive answer above.

Answer (score 20):

If you are using windows follow these steps.

1. Make sure ubuntu and WSL 2 is installed, you can follow the instructions [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/wsl/install-manual#step-2---check-requirements-for-running-wsl-2)
2. After successful installation of ubuntu, your file system now shares the same file system with your ubuntu, this means if you want to run ubuntu commands on a folder path you have to open the corresponding terminal. If you are using Visual Studio Code, you can select the corresponding ubuntu terminal for the file directory by selecting ubuntu as the new terminal, it will open the Ubuntu terminal on the current path.
3. You can run `./vendor/bin/sail up`. Make Sure you are running the command from your project folder in Ubuntu. Usually the folder is always in `/mnt/c/users/path/to/project`.
4. If you see docker not running. Open your docker desktop, go to setting, under resources, select WSL and enable integration with your ubuntu
   [image: Integrating WSL ubuntu with docker]
5. Restart your terminal, and run the command again. Don't forget under you Ubuntu file system which is usually in `/mnt/c/users/path-to-laravel-project`.
   you should see the following for the first time. Note the folder path highlighted.[image: Laravel Sail running for the first time]
6. One last thing, in order to access your laravel app on your localhost, you have to access the WSL IP address that connects to Ubuntu. use the following command. `wsl hostname -i` it outputs an IP address like [image], Note! your IP address may be different. Navigate to the IP address on default port 80 and you should see.[image: Laravel Sail running Succesfully]

I wish you a successful project. Enjoy!!

Comment: I didn't have to do the point 6, I simply managed to connect to `localhost`. (Using Laravel Sail 1.0.1, Docker Desktop 4.25.1.)